Handle values in input field in Playwright
Lets imagine that we have a pretty simple task for PLaywright. In opened form we should refill values in the input fields. In input field 1 we should set a new value "John". In field 2 we should set new value "Doe". In common it may looks like this:

Input field page.getByPlaceholder('Applicant First Name');
Input field page.getByPlaceholder('Applicant Surname');
Submit buton

Starting doing that, there is an issue with I struggling to.

Playwright opens this form and increddibly fast setting value "John" into input field 1.
Frontend clears value "John" and puts value which goes from database.
The same way happens with input field 2.
Playwright clicks submit button.
Playwright opens again this form to check was this form edited correctly and
assertion fails due values in both input fields are not expected by the actions listed above.

So my question is - what is the better way to handle this issue?
**How to make Playwright to wait until frontend puts its own values in the field, and only then rewrite them by correct values? **
Tried a few but this is what doesn't works:
    const InputField1 = this.page.getInputByLabel('Applicant 
    First Name');
    expect(await InputField1.textContent()).not.toEqual(null);
    await assetNameInputField.clear();

    expect(await InputField1.textContent()).toMatch(/^.*$/);

    expect(await InputField1.textContent()).not.toEqual('');


Can you share the page you're automating? It's difficult to guess what the behavior is in order to write a guaranteed working answer.

Maybe use the waitForFunction() method to detect that the input value of the element is not null.
async clearInputValueAndSetNew(page, placeholderText, newValue){
const selector = `input[placeholder="${placeholder}"]`;

await page.waitForFunction(selector=>{
    const inputValue = document.querySelector(selector);
    return inputValue && inputValue.value.length > 0;

},selector);

const inputField = await page.locator(selector);
const inputField.fill('') // clear the value
await inputField.fill(newValue);

}


Use toHaveValue:
Before updating the input value , make sure the expected(or anything other than blank) values are populated from the DB:
Usage:
const InputField1 = this.page.getInputByLabel('Applicant First Name');
await expect(InputField1).toHaveValue(/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/); //atleast 1 alphanumeric character

Note: toHaveValue ensures the Locator points to an element with the given input value. You can use regular expressions for the value as well.
